# akka clustering doesn't send MemberLeft event

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I use **MemeberLeft** event to clean up legacy data. I find the node(Ip: 192.168.12.212) leave and new node(Ip: 192.168.12.250) start up, but no **MemberLeft** event log can be found. Only MemberJoined event can be found. node(Ip: 192.168.12.212) could have JVM problem.

Log as follows:

```
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:23,195[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-20[0;39m] [35ma.m.c.b.i.BootstrapCoordinator[0;39m - [36mLooking up [Lookup(guandata-server,None,Some(tcp))]
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:23,195[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-20[0;39m] [35ma.d.k.KubernetesApiServiceDiscovery[0;39m - [36mQuerying for pods with label selector: [app=guandata-server]. Namespace: [default]. Port: [None]
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:23,330[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3[0;39m] [35ma.m.c.b.i.BootstrapCoordinator[0;39m - [36mLocated service members based on: [Lookup(guandata-server,None,Some(tcp))]: [ResolvedTarget(192-168-64-250.default.pod.cluster.local,None,Some(/192.168.64.250)), ResolvedTarget(192-168-66-128.default.pod.cluster.local,None,Some(/192.168.66.128)), ResolvedTarget(192-168-65-229.default.pod.cluster.local,None,Some(/192.168.65.229))], filtered to [192-168-64-250.default.pod.cluster.local:0, 192-168-66-128.default.pod.cluster.local:0, 192-168-65-229.default.pod.cluster.local:0]
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:23,351[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-26[0;39m] [35ma.m.c.b.i.BootstrapCoordinator[0;39m - [36mLocated service members based on: [Lookup(guandata-server,None,Some(tcp))]: [ResolvedTarget(192-168-64-250.default.pod.cluster.local,None,Some(/192.168.64.250)), ResolvedTarget(192-168-66-128.default.pod.cluster.local,None,Some(/192.168.66.128)), ResolvedTarget(192-168-65-229.default.pod.cluster.local,None,Some(/192.168.65.229))], filtered to [192-168-64-250.default.pod.cluster.local:0, 192-168-66-128.default.pod.cluster.local:0, 192-168-65-229.default.pod.cluster.local:0]
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:23,445[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-36[0;39m] [35ma.m.c.b.i.BootstrapCoordinator[0;39m - [36mContact point [akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.66.128:25520] returned [2] seed-nodes [akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.65.229:25520, akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.66.128:25520]
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:23,461[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-36[0;39m] [35ma.m.c.b.i.BootstrapCoordinator[0;39m - [36mContact point [akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.65.229:25520] returned [2] seed-nodes [akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.65.229:25520, akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.66.128:25520]
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:23,465[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-36[0;39m] [35ma.m.c.b.i.BootstrapCoordinator[0;39m - [36mJoining [akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.64.250:25520] to existing cluster [akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.65.229:25520, akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.66.128:25520]
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:23,633[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-36[0;39m] [35ma.m.c.b.c.HttpClusterBootstrapRoutes[0;39m - [36mBootstrap request from 192.168.64.250:49804: Contact Point returning 0 seed-nodes []
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:23,736[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-36[0;39m] [35ma.a.LocalActorRef[0;39m - [36mMessage [akka.management.cluster.bootstrap.contactpoint.HttpBootstrapJsonProtocol$SeedNodes] from Actor[akka://ClusterSystem/system/bootstrapCoordinator/contactPointProbe-192-168-64-250.default.pod.cluster.local-8558#-1278944557] to Actor[akka://ClusterSystem/system/bootstrapCoordinator/contactPointProbe-192-168-64-250.default.pod.cluster.local-8558#-1278944557] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior then Actor[akka://ClusterSystem/system/bootstrapCoordinator/contactPointProbe-192-168-64-250.default.pod.cluster.local-8558#-1278944557] may have terminated unexpectedly. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:23,984[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-20[0;39m] [35ma.c.Cluster[0;39m - [36mCluster Node [akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.64.250:25520] - Received InitJoinAck message from [Actor[akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.66.128:25520/system/cluster/core/daemon#-1974909478]] to [akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.64.250:25520]
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:24,094[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3[0;39m] [35ma.c.Cluster[0;39m - [36mCluster Node [akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.64.250:25520] - Welcome from [akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.66.128:25520]
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:24,110[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-36[0;39m] [35ms.c.MemberEventMonitorActor$[0;39m - [36m===> message received: MemberJoined(Member(akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.64.250:25520, Joining))
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:24,115[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-36[0;39m] [35ms.c.MemberEventMonitorActor$[0;39m - [36m
[Cluster State] leaders: List()
[Cluster State] members: List(Member(akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.64.250:25520, Joining), Member(akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.65.229:25520, Up), Member(akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.66.128:25520, Up))
[Cluster State] unreachable: List()

[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:24,124[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-36[0;39m] [35ms.c.MemberEventMonitorActor$[0;39m - [36m[MemberUp] ===> 192.168.65.229 up cluster
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:24,124[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-36[0;39m] [35ms.c.MemberEventMonitorActor$[0;39m - [36m
[Cluster State] leaders: List()
[Cluster State] members: List(Member(akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.64.250:25520, Joining), Member(akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.65.229:25520, Up), Member(akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.66.128:25520, Up))
[Cluster State] unreachable: List()

[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:24,124[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-36[0;39m] [35ms.c.MemberEventMonitorActor$[0;39m - [36m[MemberUp] ===> 192.168.66.128 up cluster
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:24,125[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-36[0;39m] [35ms.c.MemberEventMonitorActor$[0;39m - [36m
[Cluster State] leaders: List()
[Cluster State] members: List(Member(akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.64.250:25520, Joining), Member(akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.65.229:25520, Up), Member(akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.66.128:25520, Up))
[Cluster State] unreachable: List()

[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:24,988[0;39m [[31mmain[0;39m] [35mc.g.f.i.GuandataFileSystemFactory[0;39m - [36mfile:/// fileSystem has been created ......
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:25,070[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3[0;39m] [35ms.c.MemberEventMonitorActor$[0;39m - [36m[MemberUp] ===> 192.168.64.250 up cluster
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:25,071[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-20[0;39m] [35ma.c.s.SplitBrainResolver[0;39m - [36mThis node is now the leader responsible for taking SBR decisions among the reachable nodes (more leaders may exist).
[0;39m[[1;31mINFO[0;39m] [34m2023-07-11 08:13:25,070[0;39m [[31mClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3[0;39m] [35ms.c.MemberEventMonitorActor$[0;39m - [36m
[Cluster State] leaders: List(akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.65.229:25520)
[Cluster State] members: List(Member(akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.64.250:25520, Up), Member(akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.65.229:25520, Up), Member(akka://ClusterSystem@192.168.66.128:25520, Up))
[Cluster State] unreachable: List()
```

I want to known why akka clustering doesn't send MemberEvent. And which event I can use to judge the node status?

Answer (score 2):

`MemberLeft` only happens when a node a goes from [`Up` to `Leaving`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/cluster-membership.html#state-diagrams), which is the "graceful exit".  If the node did not leave gracefully (e.g. the JVM it was running on crashed, or a network issue disrupted connectivity, or it was too busy to send heartbeats due to workload (or GC pause or CPU oversubscription...)), then it will go through a different path through `Down`.

The `MemberRemoved` event is probably what you're looking for, especially if the plan is to run a cleanup from some other node of the cluster whether the removal was graceful or not.

Note that the `MemberRemoved` event might not be received if the entire cluster goes down, and that in the non-graceful case, there is no intrinsic guarantee that the affected node has actually stopped (ideally, the node has the default `run-coordinated-shutdown-when-down = on`, but that is not technically guaranteed to happen in any finite amount of time: consider what a long GC pause or a suspend/resume would result in).  In that situation where every node in the cluster crashes, manual cleanup might be required (or if the cleanup is not strictly required for correct operation, you grin and bear it), and for the second, if the cleanup would be messed up if the downed node hadn't yet stopped, delaying the actual cleanup might be a good idea.